# In zend framework, what is 'resource' ?

Tags: php, zend-framework

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are Zend Framework “Resources”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7073277/what-are-zend-framework-resources)

Is there any definition on what is zend framework resource?

Comment: In which context did you read that? Please provide a link.

Comment: everywhere in zend framework manual. such as 'resource auto-loading' and etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are refering to Resource in the `Zend_Application` package. That would be anything that can be loaded by `Zend_Application`, e.g. Resources to load and initialize at bootstrap.

> `Zend_Application_Resource` provides an interface for standard bootstrapping resources that can be loaded on demand by a bootstrap instance, as well as several default resource implementations.

See http://zendframework.com/manual/en/zend.application.theory-of-operation.html

Comment: I see, It should named 'bootstrap resource'

Answer (score 0):

> Simply, a resource is a logical entity which can be used to load & run a zend framework application and used as supply/reserve/store for the application. some resource are loaded automatically by zend framework itself and some you have to or for some resources you just provide configurations.

In Zend Framework, resource term used in the context of zf application to denote the followings like:
- cachemanager
- db
- multidb
- frontController
- layout
- locale
- log
- mail
- modules
- navigation
- router
- session
- translate adapter resource
- useragent
- view etc.

**Syntax: Zend_Application_Resource_ResourceName**

Sample resource loading description:

### **Zend_Application_Resource_Modules**

Zend_Application_Resource_Modules is used to initialize your application modules.
If your module has a *Bootstrap.php* file in its root, and it contains a class named _Module_Bootstrap_ (where "Module" is the module name), then it will use that class to bootstrap the module.

By default, an instance of _Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader_ will be created for the module, using the module name and directory to initialize it.

Since the Modules resource does not take any arguments by default, in order to enable it via configuration, you need to create it as an empty array. In INI(*application.ini*) style configuration, this looks like:

```
  resources.modules[] =
```

In XML style configuration, this looks like:

```
  <resources>

      <modules>

          <!-- Placeholder to ensure an array is created -->

          <placeholder />

      </modules>

  </resources>
```

Using a standard PHP array, simply create it as an empty array:

```
  $options = array(

      'resources' => array(

          'modules' => array(),

      ),

  );
```